# BigQuery Timestamp Not Getting Parsed

Tags: json, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

Using AppEngine/BigQuery. Timestamp has stopped parsing.

Here is my Schema:

```
[
    {"name":"RowID","type":"string"},
    {"name":"Timestamp","type":"timestamp"},
    {"name":"Keyword","type":"string"},
    {"name":"Engine","type":"string"},
    {"name":"Locale","type":"string"},
    {"name":"Geo","type":"string"},
    {"name":"Device","type":"string"},
    {"name":"Metrics","type":"record", "fields":[
        {"name":"GlobalSearchVolume","type":"integer"},
        {"name":"CPC","type":"float"},
        {"name":"Competition","type":"float"}
    ]}
]
```

and here is a JSON row that is being shipped to BQ for this schema:

```
{
   "RowID":"6263121748743343555",
   "Timestamp":"2015-01-13T07:04:05.999999999Z",
   "Keyword":"buy laptop",
   "Engine":"google",
   "Locale":"en_us",
   "Geo":"",
   "Device":"d",
   "Metrics":{
      "GlobalSearchVolume":3600,
      "CPC":7.079999923706055,
      "Competition":1
   }
}
```

This data is accepted by BigQuery, but the timestamp is nil (`1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`) as seen here: 
[image]

I have also tried sending through the UNIX timestamp, to no avail. Can you see any errors with my schema or input data that would cause the timestamp to not parse?

Comment: The timestamp parsing seems to have just updated (over an hour later). The timestamp shows the correct value now. Any insights into why it would take so long to parse??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue, but I was just checking the details in the preview window. When I actually ran any queries, the timestamps worked correctly. It often took 24 hours for the details to update the timestamps to the actual values.